# Using a function in d3.arc attributes

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to set each arc's startAngle to one of my properties in my data. However when I try to use the same method as setting the width with a 'rect', the function does not run...

I am trying to replicate the way I am getting my width(for a `'rect'`) in this excample:

```
            svg.selectAll('rect').data(data)
                .enter().append('rect')
                    .attr('width', d => d.duration)  // <-----
                    .attr('height', 100)
```

But when I do the same with an `arc` the function fails:

```
            dogn.selectAll('path').data(data)
                .enter().append('path')
                    .attr('d', d3.arc()({
                        innerRadius: ringWidth,
                        outerRadius: (ringWidth / 1.25),
                        startAngle: d => d.duration, // <-----
                        endAngle: 2*Math.PI
                    }));
```

How can I get the `startAngle` to be the corresponding

I get the following error when using the function for `startAngle`:

```
Error: <path> attribute d: Expected number, "MNaN,NaNL-2.20436…".
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this for your rectangles...

```
.attr('width', d => d.duration)
```

... you are retrieving the bound datum in the anonymous function, which is its first argument (idiomatically named `d`, but you can use any name).

However, for your arcs, you are not retrieving any bound datum, and the object `d` simply doesn't exist.

The solution is wrapping all `d3.arc` in an anonymous function, which receives the first argument:

```
.attr('d', function(d) {
  //1st argument----^
  return d3.arc()({
    innerRadius: ringWidth,
    outerRadius: (ringWidth / 1.25),
    startAngle: d.duration,//using the bound datum here
    endAngle: 2 * Math.PI
  })
});
```

Here is a demo, have a look how each arc has a different start angle (in radians):

```js
const svg = d3.select("svg")
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(150,75)");
const data = [0.5, 1, 2];
const arcs = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append('path')
  .attr('d', function(d, i) {
    return d3.arc()({
      innerRadius: 20 + i * 10,
      outerRadius: 30 + i * 10,
      startAngle: d,
      endAngle: 2 * Math.PI
    })
  })
  .style("fill", function(_, i) {
    return d3.schemeCategory10[i]
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Comment: I am utterly amazed by how quickly you replied! In depth explanation and working code snippet :D. This solves my problem perfectly (albeit the input needing more tweaking for it to be displayed properly), thank you very much!